# Update partial view on partial view's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working just one week with ASP.NET MVC 3. This might be a very basic question or someone might have asked similar question before. I am seeking help to show me right path/method to accomplish the problem I am facing getting the partial view designed.

I have created a partial view login (in side bar) as below. What I would like to achieve here is, when I hit the "login" button, I must be a able update the partial view with information such as

**Welcome [UserName]

Last SuccessFul Login : [DateTime]

Member Since : [Date]**

I am not sure if I need to create another partial view to display this information Or the login partial view can be updated on the fly based on the action.

### Login Partial View

```
@model AlanBeezLab.Models.LoginModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login","UserLogin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =Model.UserName }))
{
    <div >User Name
    @Html.TextBox(" ")
    </div>
    <div>Password
    @Html.Password(" ")
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Let me in!" /></p>

}
```

### Below is the _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       <!--link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />-->
      <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="Header" style="background-image: url('/Content/Images/Banner_Final3.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width :1500px; height : 150px;"   >

   </div>
  <div id="SideBar">
       @Html.Partial("UserControls/UserLogin", new AlanBeezLab.Models.LoginModel())
   </div>
   <div id="Content">
        @RenderBody()
   </div>
   <div id="Footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; XXXXX</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Below is the Login Controller

```
public class UserLoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /UserLogin/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return [Not Sure];
    }
```

I am not sure if this is best/right approach to accomplish this. I would appreciate if I am directed to the right path/approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this discussion with my peers before.

IMO login/logout should not be done via AJAX, it should be a regular HTTP POST.

Why? Well what if your on a page that requires Administrator access, then you logout via AJAX? Your still on the page - when you shouldn't be authorized to do so (unless of course you update the main portion of the page as well, which is kind of silly)

So my advice - make the login button do a regular POST to an action method, then use the PRG pattern to redirect back to the original page.

Of course, if you don't have the concept of administrators/permissions/roles then an AJAX login/logout will be fine.

Regardless, you've done the right thing with the partial view.

Your partial view should figure out if the user is authenticated, then render an appropriate editor/display template based on that.

E.g: `_Login.cshtml`:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
   @Html.DisplayFor(Context.User.Identity)
} else {
   @* editor fields *@
}
```

Comment: I do not have any plan to use Administrator role at this point of time. The above should work for me. Thanks a lot.